# 1010 data api date time conversions

Tags: 1010data

Is their a way to convert retrieved data from 1010 api to following format.

Stored Format : 20161020
Expected Format : Oct 20

I want to do this in 1010data Query itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1010data APIs and SDKs send data back unformatted. Thus, in order to return the data in the format you want you must perform string manipulation on it. In your case, you could use the following syntax to get the format you want:

```
<willbe name="string_date" value="splice(case(month(date_col);1;'Jan';2;'Feb';3;'Mar';4;'Apr';5;'May';6;'Jun';7;'Jul';8;'Aug';9;'Sep';10;'Oct';11;'Nov';12;'Dec';NA) day(date_col);' ')"/>
```

You can read about all string manipulation functions here: [1010data String Functions](https://www2.1010data.com/documentationcenter/beta/1010dataReferenceManual/Functions/StringFunctions/StringFunctions.html)

Once you've identified and performed the formatting you want, you can use the API to retrieve the clean data. Below is an example of the full API call in Python 2.7. For reference, [1010data API Documentation](https://www2.1010data.com/documentationcenter/prod/XMLAPI/index_frames.html)

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

def post(url=None, body=None):
    return urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, body, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})).read().decode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www2.1010data.com/cgi-bin/prod-stable/gw.k?protocol=xml-rpc&apiversion=3&uid=UID"
    response = post(url + "&pswd=PWD&api=login&kill=possess")
    tree = etree.fromstring(response)
    session = {}
    for child in tree:
        session[child.tag] = child.text
    sessionurl = url + "&pswd=" + session['pswd'] + "&sid=" + session['sid'] + "&api="
    query = post(sessionurl + "query",
                 "<in><name>pub.doc.retail.salesdetail</name><ops><sel value=i_=1/><willbe name=\"string_date\" value=\"splice(case(month(trans_date);1;'Jan';2;'Feb';3;'Mar';4;'Apr';5;'May';6;'Jun';7;'Jul';8;'Aug';9;'Sep';10;'Oct';11;'Nov';12;'Dec';NA) day(trans_date);' ')\"/></ops></in>")
    data = post(sessionurl + "getdata",
                "<in><cols><col>string_date</col></cols></in>")
```